# How to circulate your iOS app for testing without using XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I have an initial build of my app which I want to circulate for testing to few others who do not have XCode with them. All I want to do is pass them the binary which they will install to their devices using iTunes. I have created my developer certificate, created an app id and added the device udids in my provisioning portal. 
So now can I directly email them the binary and ask them to drag and drop into itunes and then on the device ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I tested it myself and it's amazing: You should try [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/).

It's a simple to use service (free) that allows you to distribute your adHoc builds easy and fast (might sound like advertising but it's really one of the best tools I came across).

Comment: Ditto, we use TestFlight, pretty spectacular.

Answer (score 0):

Build archive and it will appear in organizer. There is big Share button that allows you to save ipa file which you pass on to testers.